# Reading CSV file with Chinese Character [One character cannot be shown]

Tags: csv, unicode, chinese-locale

When I am opening a csv file containing Chinese characters, using Microsoft Excel, TextWrangler and Sublime Text, there are some Chinese words, which cannot be displayed properly. I have no ideas why this is the case.

Specifically, the csv file can be found in the following link: https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/plw/csv/List_of_Current_SEHK_EP.CSV

One of the word that cannot be displayed correctly is shown here: 
[image]

As you can see a ? can be found.

Using mac file command as suggested by 
http://osxdaily.com/2015/08/11/determine-file-type-encoding-command-line-mac-os-x/ tell me that the csv format is utf-16le.

I am wondering what's the problem, why I cannot read that specific text? 
Is it related to encoding? Or is it related to my laptop setting? Trying to use Mac and windows 10 on Mac (via Parallel Desktop) cannot display the work correctly.

Thanks for the help. I really want to know why this specific text cannot be displayed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual name of HSBC Broking Securities is:

> 滙豐金融證券(香港)有限公司

The first character, U+6ED9 `滙`, is one of the troublesome [HKSCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Supplementary_Character_Set) characters: characters that weren't available in standard pre-Unicode Big-5, which were grafted on in incompatible ways later.

For a while there was an unfortunate convention of converting these characters into Private Use Area characters when converting to Unicode. This data was presumably converted back then and is now mangled, replacing `滙` with U+E05E `` Private Use Area Character.

For PUA cases that you're sure are the result of HKSCS-compatibility-bodge, you can convert back to proper Unicode using [this table](http://www.ogcio.gov.hk/en/business/tech_promotion/ccli/terms/doc/2003cmp.txt).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. It works now. But I have something unclear still. What does the 2 columns, Compatibility points of HKSCS-2004 in ISO/IEC 10646:2003 with Amendment 1 and Actual ISO 10646 code in ISO/IEC 10646:2003 with Amendment 1, exactly mean? 

In addition, how can I ensure which character in the csv needs transformation using such map, which don't? Thanks.